# Maximization with Lagrangian Multiplier Method (3 constraints & 3 variables)

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier, economics

I have to obtain the optimal levels of $ {C_1}_t^{'},{C_2}_t^{'}, and {K_{t+1}}^{'}   $

$$ \max   \overline{U} = log{C_1}_t^{'} + \beta log{C_2}_t^{'} $$

subject to constraints:

$$ {C_1}_t^{'} + {K_{t+1}}^{'} = w_t $$
$$ {C_2}_t^{'} = (1 + r_{t+1}){K_{t+1}}^{'} $$
$$ {C_1}_t^{'} \geq 0, {C_2}_t^{'} \geq 0, {K_{t+1}}^{'} \geq 0 $$

My question is: How do I set up the Lagrangian equation? Do I have to rearrange the constraints such that I get rid of $ w_t $ and $ r_{t+1}$ ?

Comment: I assume that $\beta, r_{t+1}, w_t$ are fixed constants in this optimisation problem

Comment: You can have a Lagrange multiplier for each constraint, then you need to test if each constraint is binding. These are the KKT conditions. You don't want to get rid of your parameters.